# Relative positioning div overlapping bottom content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to do a mobile first responsive layout. So on my HTML I have

```
First - Middle Content
Then - Left Content
Then - Right Content
```

and below all the content, I have a separate section of information that goes full width from left to right.

I'm using `position:absolute` for Middle,Left and Right `div`s to position them. My problem is, because the main 3 `div`s are absolutely positioned, the separate section goes below the main content and overlaps. How can I fix this?

I have a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKKcq/1/).

Comment: Please only use `code formatting` for... well, code.

Comment: Have you tried using Twitter Bootstrap? It solves a lot of your layout problems before you even face them!

Comment: @StijnHaus : Actually this site is an already built one. So Im trying to use media queries to change the layout

Comment: I think this could be done in a better fashion. Have you tried using `floats` or changing the display to `inline-block`. Absolute positioning really doesn't seem to be the best choice for this type of layout, unless I am misunderstanding your intention.

Comment: @user1889007 I'm with Calvin on this. Absolute position is definitely *not* the way to go, as absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the page, and responsive design is all about altering the flow of the page to fit the viewport. Can't do that when there's no flow...

Comment: @calvin. Thanks. I tried floats first, but I couldnt get the left column to go below the middle column when page resized. Can you please provide me an example how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic floats example: http://jsfiddle.net/UKKcq/11 
Basic display: inline-block example: http://jsfiddle.net/UKKcq/19/

There's a fair few things to consider here:

First, you'll notice in the second example, the text from the main section starts below all 3 divs. This is because they are still part of the flow of the document whereas when using floats they are not so the text wraps around them.

Also, with the second example, I had to delete all spacing/line breaks between the divs to stop a space appearing in-between them. This happens all the time with inline-blocks and I use the following jQuery function to fix it to avoid ruining the neatness of my markup:

```
jQuery.fn.cleanWhitespace = function() {
            textNodes = this.contents().filter(
                function() { return (this.nodeType == 3 &&    !/\S/.test(this.nodeValue)); })
                .remove();
            return this;
        }
})();

$('INSERTPARENTDIVHERE').cleanWhitespace();
```

Furthermore, I had to use `vertical-align:top` as by default the shortest `div` (in this case the center), was aligning with the bottom of the other two `divs`.

One final consideration is that `inline-block` layouts such as this have a tendency to break when the user zooms using their browser or if the width, padding, border or margin were to change for any reason. You have relative control over the latter factors but to ensure things aren't dropping to the next line (which can look really bad) when the user zooms I recommend applying `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent `div` to try and prevent this.